# Is it possible to do a dropna-like operation before creating a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a DataFrame with more than 500 rows, derived from an API query. When I check the length of my arrays, as so:

```
print(len(cities), len(country), len(max_temp), len(latit), len(longit), len(humid_), len(cloud_), len(wind))
```

I get the following output:

```
577 526 526 526 526 526 526 526
```

Now, I read the answers about casting these to Series, which adds NaN to the empty cells. The problem is that this mismatches the column values, i.e., all the numeric values are listed first, then all the NaN's at the end. This will cause the country, max_temp, etc., to line up with the wrong city. What I want to do is have the NaN appear in the correct row of each city with missing data. I could simply dropna if I had a DataFrame; but with the different array lengths, I cannot get a DataFrame.

Okay, editing in light of the comments: I began with a randomly generated list of coordinates, then:

```
for lat_lng in lat_lngs:
    city = citipy.nearest_city(lat_lng[0], lat_lng[1]).city_name

    # If the city is unique, then add it to a our cities list
    if city not in cities:
        cities.append(city)
```

This generated a list of cities. Then I did:

```
country = []
latit = []
longit = []
max_temp = []
humid_ = []
cloud_ = []
wind = []
for city in cities:
    try:
        query_url = base_url + "q=" + city + "&appid=" + weather_api_key
        response = requests.get(query_url).json()
        country.append(response['sys']['country'])
        latit.append(response['coord']['lat'])
        longit.append(response['coord']['lon'])
        max_temp.append(response['main']['temp_max'])
        humid_.append(response['main']['humidity'])
        cloud_.append(response['clouds']['all'])
        wind.append(response['wind']['speed'])
    except:
        print(f'Data not found.')
```

What I believe is occurring is that I am getting an array something like this:

```
City     Country     Max Temp     (etc.)
Boston     US          30           (etc.)
Honolulu                              
Rome        IT         27
Vladivostok RU          20
```

In this example, "Honolulu" had no data, so generated a row with only the city Column filled. I can't be sure, since I can't view it as a DataFrame. What I want to do is either put NaN in the same row as Honolulu, or drop the row with Honolulu.

Comment: mock up an example with say, 3 arrays with length 7, 6, and 5, and show your desired output from that example

Comment: It might be easier to work with this earlier in your program. In what format do you first receive the data?

Comment: AMC: I began with a list of cities: `for lat_lng in lat_lngs:
    city = citipy.nearest_city(lat_lng[0], lat_lng[1]).city_name
    
    # If the city is unique, then add it to a our cities list
    if city not in cities:
        cities.append(city)` Then I made a series of API hits to acquire: ` country = []
latit = []
longit = []
max_temp = []
humid_ = []
cloud_ = []
wind = [] ` Using .append each time a data point was found, in a Try loop since I knew that some would not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after consulting with an expert offline, I got this solution:

In my lists of variables, add a new one:

```
new_city = []
country = []
latit = []
longit = []
max_temp = []
humid_ = []
cloud_ = []
wind = []
```

Then, in my Try loop:

```
for city in cities:
    try:
        query_url = base_url + "q=" + city + "&appid=" + weather_api_key
        response = requests.get(query_url).json()
        new_city.append(response['name])
        country.append(response['sys']['country'])
        latit.append(response['coord']['lat'])
        longit.append(response['coord']['lon'])
        max_temp.append(response['main']['temp_max'])
        humid_.append(response['main']['humidity'])
        cloud_.append(response['clouds']['all'])
        wind.append(response['wind']['speed'])
    except:
        print(f'Data not found.')
```

And finally, build my dataframe with that new_city variable instead of the original city variable. This gives me all lists of the same length.